# Excel date format differ from CSV file

Tags: excel, powerquery, export-to-excel

I am working on excel query, my data source is a CSV file.
The date format extracted is 8/1/2023 which is 1st of Aug ( it is in the DB I Checked)
The excel Query reads it 8th of Jan

I tried to change the date type by right click on the Colum --> change type --> Using local ( tried most of the option in it )
Still not reading the correct date ( 1st of Aug )

Comment: It might help if you edit your question to post your code from home ... advanced editor ...

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so please toggle the checkmark on that answer to mark question as solved

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to be careful about the sequence of your actions:

1. Import CSV
2. Modify column formatting

=> wrong result.

1. Modify column formatting
2. Import CSV

=> result should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read in the column as text, then convert it using

```
Date.From([DateColumnName], "en-US")
```

such as

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"YourPriorStepNameGoesHere",{{"YourDateColumnNameGoesHere", each Date.From(_, "en-EN"), type date}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by `Excel Query` you mean `Power Query`, after you import the data, at the bottom of the Screen select `Edit`. This will open the PQ UI. On the right hand margin should be a section titled `Applied Steps`.

- Select the `#"Changed Type" step.
- Right click on the date column

  - From the drop down menu select
    -`Change Type => Using Locale`
  - Select `Date` and the `locale` for the CSV file -- probably `English(United States)` if the date format ***in the text csv file*** is `MDY`

[image]

***Note: to determine the format of the date in the CSV file, you must open it in a text editor (eg `Notepad` or `Notepad++`) and examine the file.***

If that doesn't work, please supply

- Data ***AS TEXT*`** that will replicate your problem
- Your computer's ***Windows Regional Settings*** for `Date`
- Your code as listed in the PQ `Advanced Editor`