# How to stop Excel from overwriting column's format settings when importing data from a .csv

Tags: excel, csv, powerquery

I'm trying to import some data in Excel from a .csv file.
For some reasons, I don't understand, excel will change the formatting settings of the date cells.
Specifically, In the .csv file I have a Data format Settings: YYYY-MM-GG.
I would like to keep the format coherent, but excel automatically change it in the format: GG-MM-YYYY.
There is any way to avoid this, other than just change back the data format in Power Query?

Thanks

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77080259/excel-date-format-differ-from-csv-file/77081291#77081291

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.